# Linebreak in a String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

I want to make a linkebreak in a String. In HTML it's like this (if I replace the T with a linkebreak):
`mystring.replace("T", "<br>");`

But this doesn't work in JavaScript. The `<br>` is part of the String too. How do I implement this in JavaScript? Thanks!

**mystring BEFORE linkebreak:**

2013-10-22T22:56:25.534Z

**mystring AFTER linebreak:**

2013-10-22T

22:56:25.534Z

Comment: That depends on where you are putting the string. Are you putting it in a `console.log`? In an `alert`? In the DOM itself? In a text file?

Comment: if you want `T` also why are you replacing it?

Comment: Hi everyone. Thanks for your replies. 'mystring.replace("T", "T\n");' works pretty well. It works in 'alert' and in 'console.log' as well. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me, because I use a rickshaw diagram and I try to put this String as a x-axis label. It doesn't work because of the rickshaw library, but that's another topic. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by doing like :

```
var mystring = "2013-10-22T22:56:25.534Z";

console.log(mystring.replace("T", "\n"));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/un49x1w2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
"2013-10-22T22:56:25.534Z".replace("T", "\n");
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Answer (score 0):

is used for html, in javascript normal new line character '\n' will do the trick, so you need to replace T with this new line character '\n' rather than

```
mystring.replace("T", "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the T in your statement you can do something like

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/T/, "T\n");
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5zeoqvz/)